# How do I get out of the hole with my stuff?

Tags: candy-box-2

So I can get to the chests in the hole ok, but I can't get out and keep my stuff, what do I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use teleport, then navigate to the very bottom of the cave. That gives you a valid exit option.

Answer (score 1):

Get the pogo stick by clicking on the asterisk inside the cave of the mountain. This will allow you to jump in quests. When used with the anti gravity potion, this allows you to jump out of the chest area and to the bottom of the cave.

Answer (score 0):

You could use rocket boots, if somehow you got the desert fortress key before that chest.

You still need teleport spell either way.